# Initialiser, specific member of a union

Tags: c++, winapi, unions

I have a feeling the answer to this question is no, but is it possible to initialise a specific member of a union?  For example the following:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto time = 20090520145024798ull;

    auto large = ULARGE_INTEGER() = {           
        { time }
    };

    assert(large.QuadPart == time);

    return 0;
}
```

(Visual Studio 2013, Windows 10), produces a compiler "conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to 'DWORD'", implying it's going to try to shoe-horn the uint64_t into the DWORD.

ULARGE_INTEGER is the union:

```
typedef union _ULARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        DWORD HighPart;
    } u;
    ULONGLONG QuadPart;
} ULARGE_INTEGER;
```

What does the standard say about order of initialisation in cases like this?  I had hoped the compiler would see that QuadPart was the appropriate member to assign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With unions, you can use list-initialization to initialize the first member only, as per [dcl.init.aggr]:

> When a union is initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer, the braces shall only contain an *initializer-clause*
>   for the first non-static data member of the union. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> union u { int a; const char* b; };
> u a = { 1 };
> u b = a;
> u c = 1; // error
> u d = { 0, "asdf" }; // error
> u e = { "asdf" }; // error
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

So, in your example, the following:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER large{time};
```

would initialize `u.LowPart`, not `QuadPart`, regardless of what the types of the various members are.

If you want to do anything else, you'll have to be explicit about it:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER large;
large.QuadPart = time;
```

Or write a better `union` type that actually has a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping it simple:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER large;
large.QuadPart = time;
```

Or if you want to use auto and initialize it in one line, make a little helper perhaps?

```
inline auto MAKE_ULARGE_INTEGER(ULONGLONG t)
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER result;
    result.QuadPart = t;
    return result;
}

auto large = MAKE_ULARGE_INTEGER(time);
```

Comment: That's the only way tho. Or as I've said make a little helper (which matches the style of the ULARGE_INTEGER like I did). And you can use auto as well.

Comment: Everyone and their dog seems to be (ab)using `auto` for everything. This is certainly not a case where `auto` should be used at all. It is helpful when writing library code, where you don't know the concrete type. It should not ever be used when you know the type. Code should be readable, even if you don't load it up in a code editor displaying tooltips that show the concrete type (e.g. sample code in documentation, publishes as HTML, or this web page).

Comment: Just to be clear. Which auto are you talking about, the first one used in the function, or the second one? Either way, perhaps you should have used another example to complain. If you are working with this code you know the type of auto large = MAKE_ULARGE_INTEGER(time) is clearly ULARGE_INTEGER just by reading the function name, it's very clear. As for the auto in the function, exactly the same thing.

Comment: But **why** use `auto` at all? You know the type. Just spell it out. I should not have to look through implementations (or trust a function name) to find out, what `auto` means. What have you gained from using `auto` (both occurrences) over using the specific type?